# Pass more than filename argument to stat()?

Tags: linux

I'd like to know if it's possible (no matter why) to pass more than just a filename for existing file to stat() function, so it would not fail and return 0?

I mean like this:

```
struct stat mystat; char file[100];
...
if(stat(file, &mystat)==0){
//success
}
```

Is it possible to specify file as "existing-file_**some_special_chars_maybe**_some-text" and to stat() not fail on that?

Comment: you mean with wildcards?

Comment: I don't think this makes any sense. You have to pass a filename to `stat()`. If you pass anything else it will fail. That's just how it works.

Answer (score 1):

`stat()` works on filenames, so if you're passing in something that isn't a filename, you shouldn't be surprised that it fails. You can use `fstat()` to get information on whatever file a file handle is pointing to, but otherwise you're stuck with just filenames.

Answer (score 0):

How about just creating a list of file names and feeding them to `stat()` one by one?